# how to get value using latest date from one table and joining to another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have 1 table inventory_movement here is data in table

```
product_id | staff_name |  status | sum | reference_number
--------------------------------------------------
  1          zes             cp     1    000122
  2          shan             cp     4    000133
```

i have another table inventory_orderproduct where i have cost date

```
 orderdate   product_id   cost
--------------------------------
01/11/2018    1            3200
01/11/2018    2             100
02/11/2018    1            4000
02/11/2018    1            500
03/11/2018    2            2000
```

i want this result

```
product_id| staff_name | status | sum reference_number  |  cost
--------------------------------------------------------------
      1         zes        cp     1    000122         4000
      2         shan       cp     4    000133         2000
```

here is my query

```
select ipm.product_id, 
case when ipm.order_by_id is not null then 
(select au.first_name from users_staffuser us inner join auth_user au on us.user_id= au.id
where us.id = ipm.order_by_id) else '0' end as "Staff_name"
,ipm.status,
Sum(ipm.quantity), ip.reference_number
from inventory_productmovement ipm
inner join inventory_product ip on ipm.product_id = ip.id
inner join users_staffuser us on ip.branch_id = us.branch_id 
inner join auth_user au on us.user_id = au.id
AND ipm.status = 'CP'
group by ipm.product_id, au.first_name, ipm.status,  
ip.reference_number, ip.product_name
order by 1
```

Comment: What's the cost column supposed to return?

Comment: I think the result u want is 4000 and 2000 not 40000,20000 right?

Comment: @Sorix maximum value

Comment: @SahilAnand yes..

Comment: Please add a little more information to your question. Do you want MAX of **costs of every distinct product_id** , displayed in a joined table with latter one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to get MAX cost for products

```
SELECT i.product_id,i.staff_name,i.status,i.sum reference_number ,s.MAXCost
FROM (SELECT product_id,MAX(cost) AS MAXCost
    FROM inventory_orderproduct 
    GROUP BY product_id ) s
JOIN inventory_movement i  ON i.product_id =s.product_id
```

For Retrieving the cost using the latest date use the below query

```
WITH cte as (
   SELECT product_id,cost
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY orderdate DESC) AS Rno
   FROM inventory_orderproduct )
 SELECT i.product_id,i.staff_name,i.status,i.sum reference_number ,s.Cost
 FROM cte s
 JOIN inventory_movement i  ON i.product_id =s.product_id 
 WHERE s.Rno=1
```

Comment: @Sanal Sunny your answer is correct but if we have inventory_orderproduct date and we want cost using latest date. how can we get this cost?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of your question.its working fine.if you like the answer please vote!

```
SELECT i.product_id,i.staff_name,i.status,i.sum reference_number ,s.Cost
FROM (SELECT product_id,MAX(cost) AS Cost
    FROM inventory_orderproduct 
    GROUP BY product_id ) s
JOIN inventory_movement i  ON i.product_id =s.product_id
```

Comment: your answer is correct but if we have inventory_orderproduct date and we want cost using latest date. how can we get this cost?

Comment: but the date column is not available in the table which you provided

Answer (score 0):

In the given situation, this should work fine:

```
Select table1.product_id, table2.staff_name, table2.status, table2.reference_number, 
MAX(table1.cost)
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.product_id = table2.product_id
GROUP BY table2.product_id, table2.staff_name, table2.status, table2.reference_number
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query it will pick the data according to the latest date

```
WITH result as (
   SELECT product_id,cost
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY date DESC)
   FROM inventory_orderproduct )
 SELECT i.product_id,i.staff_name,i.status,i.sum reference_number ,s.Cost
 FROM result s
 JOIN inventory_movement i  ON i.product_id =s.product_id
```

Comment: This won't work. What is the reason for using cte here ?